# Why can't I push in this dispatch action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I'm creating a chatroom app, and I'm just getting local functionality down at the moment. I've created a test object to hold chatroom data, including messages. Now, I have a text input field for chatting, but I can't seem to access my messages in my chatroom object to push the new message into. When I console.log the state.messages, I seem to get this weird Proxy object instead of the array of messages. Does anyone know why this is? Here's my code:

JSX:

```
<InputGroup className="mb-3">
            <FormControl aria-describedby="basic-addon1" className="chat-insert"/>
            <InputGroup.Append>
                <Button variant="outline-secondary" onClick={() => {
                    dispatch(addChat(document.querySelector('.chat-insert').value));
                    document.querySelector('.chat-insert').value = '';
                }}>Send</Button>
           </InputGroup.Append>
</InputGroup>
```

Data Object:

```
let chatData = [
    {
        name: "General Chatroom",
        private: false,
        passcode: null,
        currentUsers: [],
        messages: [
            {
                avatar: "#",
                username: 'Chatter[bot]',
                message: `Welcome to Chatter[box]! This is the beginning of this chatroom's history!`
            },
        ]
    }
]

export default chatData
```

Reducer:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import chatData from '../../components/chatData'

export const chatSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'chat',
    initialState: chatData[0],
    reducers: {
        addChat: (state, action) => {
            console.log(chatData[0])
            state.messages.push({
                avatar: "#",
                username: "",
                message: action.payload
            })
            console.log(state.messages)
        },
    },
});

export const { addChat } = chatSlice.actions

export const selectChat = state => state.messages

export default chatSlice.reducer
```

Console Log:
[image: Console Log]

Comment: State is meant to be immutable. You should not use `Array.prototype.push` inside a reducer. You're meant to use the spread-operator `...` to *copy* `state.messages` into a new array instead.

Comment: Shallow copy existing state, and shallow copy the array, then add the new elements to the array, and don't forget to return your new state object from the reducer function.

Comment: I suspect you are seeing a javascript [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object as a redux implementation detail since you are console logging internal, intermediate "state" versus the state the reducer *should*/*would* return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `createSlice` function from Redux Toolkit uses the [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) library to allow writing reducers that directly modify state. The `state` object in your reducer is a "draft state" proxy to your current state.

To snapshot and print the "draft state" use the `current` function that Redux Toolkit re-exports from Immer. Here's an example from [Logging Draft State Values](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#logging-draft-state-values):

```
import { createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const slice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState: [{ id: 1, title: 'Example todo' }],
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      console.log('before', current(state))
      state.push(action.payload)
      console.log('after', current(state))
    },
  },
})
```